# What is the Token Lifetime an d Access Token in ADFS

Tags: authentication, saml, adfs, service-provider, idp

What is the SAML Token Lifetime and Access Token in SAML, what happens if configure RP's token lifetime is more then WebSSOLifetime.

IDP: ADFS

for example:
WebSSOLifetime = 60 RP's Token lifetime = 80

After 70 minutes, Can I able to login without authentication? what is role of this two parameters?

Comment: There's a good answer to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14867613/adfs-2-0-time-out-and-relation-between-freshness-value-tokenlifetime-and-webssol).

Comment: Hi @rbrayb,

Thanks for the information, I wanted to confirm this point with you, To prompt a user to re-authenticate, we require WebSSOLifetime to be lower than TokenLifetime. right? 

As per my understanding, the SSO login/authentication will work based on the WebSSOLifetime.  The token Lifetime period is only used to generate a token based on the  WebSSOLifetime parameter.

Comment: is that right? As per the example given above it will go back to the login page again